# Wowza Streaming Server intercept response of HLS Key Request

Tags: java, key, wowza, http-live-streaming

I came across a scenario where it is needed to intercept the response of the HLS Key request in case of AES encryption internal method.

Following are the handles given by Wowza

```
onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyCreateLive(IApplicationInstance
appInstance, String streamName, byte[] encKey)
```

Called when live stream key is requested (per-published stream)

```
void onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyCreateVOD(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino
httpSession, byte[] encKey)
```

Called when video on demand key is requested (per-session)

```
void onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyData(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino
httpSession, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp, byte[] encKeyData)
```

Called when a key data is requested.

```
void onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyLiveChunk(ILiveStreamPacketizer
liveStreamPacketizer, String streamName, CupertinoEncInfo encInfo, long
chunkId, int mode)
```

Called when live stream key is requested (per-published stream, per-chunk - for rotating keys)

```
void onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyRequest(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino
httpSession, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp)
```

Called when a key is requested.

All the above mentioned methods intercept the key request call. Is there any way in which I can intercept the key response before it is sent to the client?

Answer (score 0):

While there is a workaround to generate a custom output using the resp object of the `onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyData(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino httpCupertinoStreamingSession, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp, byte[] encKeyData)` method, the best approach is to use an external method for AES-128 encryption. You would use .key files with the same name as the stream name and include the URL to your code that would provide the key data for decryption.

The .key file would have content similar to:

```
cupertinostreaming-aes128-key: DE51A7254739C0EDF1DCE13BBB308FF0
cupertinostreaming-aes128-url: http:/mycompany.com/security.aspx
```

The .key files would need to be located in the keys/ directory of your Wowza installation, and if your VOD files are located in sub-directories, the .key files would also need to have the same sub-directory tree as your VOD files.

For example, if your VOD file sample.mp4 is located in content/subdir/, then your key file would be keys/subdir/sample.mp4.key, and your playback URL would be `http://wowzaIP:1935/vod/_definst_/mp4:subdir/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8`. You can then verify that this is working by reviewing your access logs located in logs/wowzastreamingengine_access.log file. You should see lines similar to:

```
HTTPStreamerCupertinoIndexFile.init[vod/_definst_/sample.mp4]: Encrypt Cupertino stream: key: *763a url: http://192.168.1.120:1935/vod/_definst_/mp4:sample.mp4/key{bitrate}{sessionid}.m3u8key
```

Comment: Well I have tried using the method `onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyData(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino httpCupertinoStreamingSession, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp, byte[] encKeyData)` though I observed that the wms output is being appended to my custom output. Finally I decided to go with the AES-128 external method and now I am handling the logic of key delivery